# OpenGL execution error (maybe the computer)

Tags: c++, opengl

I installed Visual Studio, CMake, GLFW and Glad to program OpenGL, and it works, there are not compilation time errors, but the program doesn't creates the window, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
 
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
 
    GLFWwindow* MyWindow = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "My First OpenGL Window", NULL, NULL);
 
    if (MyWindow == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(MyWindow);
 
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(MyWindow))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
 
    glfwDestroyWindow(MyWindow);
 
    glfwTerminate();
 
    return 0;
}
```

The only what happens is that the if condition (MyWindow = NULL) its fully executed, exiting the program with -1 code.

Comment: Check the return value of `glfwInit`, that can fail as well: `if(!glfwInit()) { std::cout << "failed to init GLFW\n"; return -2; }`

Comment: The message doesn't shows, GLFW initializes right

Comment: Does your graphics card/driver support OpenGL 3.3 Core ?

Comment: Many GLFW examples, including [tjhe official "hello world" example](https://www.glfw.org/documentation) contains one small problem: When a program exits with a failure it should return with a *small positive number*.

Comment: @RichardCritten I will check it

Comment: I'm assuming the `(MyWindow = NULL)` in the text of your question is just a typo and you actually have `(MyWindow == NULL)` as shown in the code, right?

Comment: @G.M. You'd hope so because then it would skip that `if` entirely wouldn't it, which doesn't match with what OPs asking? :p

Comment: The opengl version is 2.1 :(. If I update the drivers, I can use 3.3?

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos That depends on the graphics card, both your graphics card _and_ driver will need 3.3 support to use 3.3 features. If your card doesn't support or has no drivers that support 3.3 you'll need an upgrade

Comment: Or switch to Mesa's `llvmpipe` software rasterizer, which [should support GL 4.6 Core nowadays](https://mesamatrix.net/#OpenGL4.6).